# How to use case expression in SQL with less than or equal to operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a query where in I want to group by the rank (rn) column and show results for sales, orders, etc.

```
SELECT month, sku_id,
case when rn<=1000 then 1
     when rn<=2000 then 2
     else 3 end as rn
```

The problem here is that the first 1000 sku get labeled as rn 1 and only the next 1000 skus get labeled as rn 2, but I want the first 1000 skus also to be considered in rn. I understand that this isn't possible in a case expression, is there any workaround to this?

Comment: What do you mean by `considered in rn`?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be like this:

Use `row_number()` to give all records a unique number and then use `case` statement:

```
with cte as (
select month, 
       skuid, 
        ...
        ... --other fields as per your requirement
        row_number() over (order by some_field) as "rn" from your_table
)

SELECT month, sku_id, ....--other fields
case when rn<=1000 then 1
     when rn<=2000 then 2
     else 3 end as rn
     from cte
```